# I want to play the speech recogniser start/stop sounds in my app manually

Tags: android, voice

Basically I'm using android voice recogniser and google cloud speech api, both in my app.

For android speech recogniser there is default tones playing when start recognising and stop recognising.

I want to play same tone when I use google cloud speech api.

I tried to play sound via media player but unable to access the URI of that particular sounds. can some one help me to play that sounds.

I tried this :

```
private void playSound(){
    Uri defaultRingtoneUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);

    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

    try {
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(getContext(), defaultRingtoneUri);
        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM);
        mediaPlayer.prepare();
        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp)
            {
                mp.reset();
            }
        });
        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
            mediaPlayer.reset();
        }
        mediaPlayer.start();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException | SecurityException
            | IllegalStateException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```